# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 17:64 mismatched input '.' expecting = near 'dim' in update statement

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am updating a a table but am receiving errors.Below is my code:

```
update dim set dim.firstname=x.firstname
from 
db1.new_table1 as dim join db2.table2 as x on (x.recid=dim.recid)
where dim.firstname<>x.firstname;
```

This is my error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 17:64 mismatched input '.' expecting = near 'dim' in update statement
```

Any suggestions as to why i keep getting this error?

Comment: To begin with, are you sure Hive supports UPDATE on a JOIN?

Comment: Then look at line 17 in your script, and character 64. That's where the syntax error is.